# Can I post all Messages in rabbitmq to a REST API?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq producer sending data to a queue in rabbitmq in a docker container, I have another micro-service with only an /POST entry.

Can I POST all messages in queue to this API?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the messages in the `queue` and POST them to your API, you need to have `consumer(s)` that listens to the `queue`.